# Python while statement error

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am a beginner in python. My program is to set a number (I am not using random.randint for the moment) and I try to guess it. So here is the code:

```
def game():
    print "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10!"
    global  x
    x = 7
    y = raw_input("Guess!")
    while x > y:
        y = raw_input("Too low. Guess again!")
    while x < y:
        y = raw_input("Too high. Guess again!")
    if x == y:
        return "You got it! The number was" + x + " !"
```

but when I run this, the program states that x < y, no matter WHAT number I put in.
Please, can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: In python 3, you can no longer compare an int and a str
>>> print(1 < '2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: thanks, but i am using python 2 not 3. think it's the same thing between str and int regardless of version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert `y` to an integer before comparing it to `x`:

```
y = int(raw_input("Guess!"))
```

Otherwise, you are comparing variables of different types, and the result is not always intuitive (such as `x` always being less than `y`). You can apply the same approach for the other times you ask the user to input `y`.

Comment: Well at least convert them to be the same type.  Since the user might be a smart aleck and put an irrational number in between 1 and 10 :)

Answer (score 4):

You may want this:

```
def game():
    print "I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10!"
    global  x
    x = 7
    while True:
        y = int(raw_input("Guess! ")) # Casting the string input to int
        if x > y:
            y = raw_input("Too low. Guess again!")
        elif x < y:
            y = raw_input("Too high. Guess again!")
        elif x == y:
            print "You got it! The number was " + str(x) + " !"
            break # To exit while loop

game()
```

Answer (score 1):

Y has to be an integer like x. A simple way to do this is:

```
y=int(raw_input("etc."))
```

You cannot compare two **different** variable types in python! Hope this helps!